# Using two server side controllers in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is it allowed to use two server side controllers in lightning component?
If so how.

Like in visualforce we can extend the standard controller

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="myControllerExtension">
```

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot have to controllers for the same component. You can however extend components by marking the super component as abstract and using the extends keyword on the sub component.